# Events for loaded modules in erlang

Tags: erlang

How can I get an event when a module has been loaded in erlang?

The "event" can be in the form of execution of a fun/MFA, message to arbitrary process etc.  If there is no support in the standard lib what is the best work around?

The workarounds I can think of are:

- run a trace on the code module
- scan loaded module times in a loop

An additional restriction is that there shouldn't have to be special hooks in the module being loaded because this is for a debugging app.  Standard library modules are not expected to be reloaded and it is assumed the tools application is running.

Comment: I went with the tracing workaround in the end although I don't think it is very clean: https://github.com/andytill/erlyberly/commit/f901a6ca90a15bec37d572250a693a46b54157be

Answer (score 0):

There is `-on_load()` module directive. You can set some function to run when module is loaded using this directive. See more information in [documentation](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/code_loading.html).

Comment: It is important that there are no special hooks in the code being reloaded, this is a debugging tool so it would be very tedious to write this for every module that could get debugged.

Comment: For debugging purposes you should use debugging tools i.e. tracing.

Comment: It is a UI over tracing :D https://github.com/andytill/erlyberly (p.s. I am aware of tracing in observer)